# Spring boot entity with many to one relationship is not saving in postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have few entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user", schema = "edu", catalog = "ed_db")
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppUser {
   @Basic
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email = "";

}
```

and a teacher entity that has relationship with appuser as follows:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Teacher {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private AppUser appUser;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    @NotNull(message = "client.is_required")
    private Integer clientId;

}
```

when I try to use it in my code:

```
public Teacher save(TeacherDto teacherDto) {
        AppUser appUser = teacherDto.getAppUserEntity();
        AppUser dbAppUser = appUserService.save(appUser);
        Teacher teacher = teacherDto.getTeacherEntity();
        teacher.setAppUser(dbAppUser);
        teacher.setClientId(appUser.getClientId());

        return teacherRepository.save(teacher);
    }
```

It keeps throwing exception:

```
2022-08-19T01:20:56.052-04:00  WARN 69525 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2022-08-19T01:20:56.053-04:00 ERROR 69525 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "app_user_id" of relation "teacher" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, null, 2, 2022-08-19 01:20:56.028, 2022-08-19 01:20:56.028).
2022-08-19T01:20:56.064-04:00 ERROR 69525 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.p.exceptions.GlobalExceptionHandler  : org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [app_user_id" of relation "teacher]
```

I can't figure out what is the problem here.
in console, statements look like this:

```
insert 
    into
        edu.app_user
        (address, client_id, created_at, email, enabled, first_name, last_name, password, phone, username) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
insert 
    into
        edu.teacher
        (app_user_id, client_id, created_at, updated_at) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: You need to define the getter and setters in the child/parent entity and need to adjust the CASCADE type according to your project's workflow. Also, need to define OneToMany association in AppUser entity. Check this link for more details. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMij6c_enZ8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Probably `appUser.getClientId()` is null and you probably should use `dbAppUser.getClientId()`

Comment: but it is not complaining about `clientId` at all, it complains about `appUserId` being `null`, and I cannot get that `id` at all, `save`, `saveAndFlush` does not return `id`

Answer (score 0):

In your entity `AppUser`, `@GeneratedValue` applies to field `id` and `@Id` applies to field `username`. I guess you must move `@Id` to the field `id`.